# Saving DevExpress Ribbon Layout

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, ribbon-control

I made a devexpress ribbon and have a ribbon page for dynamic controls which gets added by the end-user. I would like to know how to save it when the form closes, so the next time the user opens he/she will have the control. Since devexpress ribbon control doesn't have `RibbonControl1.SaveLayoutToXml()`, is it possibe to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that you can save on a ribbon control is the Quick Launch items.

Comment: Thanks buddy. They should include ribbon customization.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress has this functionality (at least in the current 13.2 version)

[RibbonControl.SaveLayoutToXml](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonControl_SaveLayoutToXmltopic) and [RibbonControl.RestoreLayoutFromXml](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonControl_RestoreLayoutFromXmltopic)